# PHP mktime string not working

Tags: php, mktime

I am trying to add `$input` to my `$output` mktime string but it just returns the date today not the date +2 days (eg 2 days ahead) as desired. Can anyone help my with this please?

```
 $input = '+2';
 $output = date('j',mktime(0,0,0,date('j'), date('d'),  $input  ,date('Y')));
```

I have also tried

```
$input = +2;
$output = date('j',mktime(0,0,0,date('j'), date('d'),  $input  ,date('Y')));
```

but that did not work either.

Any help would be much appreciated, thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do:

```
date('j', mktime(0, 0, 0, date('m'), date('d') + 2, date('Y')));
```

But the easier way would probably be (and more readable one):

```
$date = strtotime('+2 days');
$output = date('j', $date);
```

Comment: Yeah, thanks for pointing that out, I actually came back with the idea of editing that. :D

Answer (score 0):

The coma before $input is messing with you. You should replace it with a + sign and only have the number of days in your $input. Like this:

```
$input = 2;
$output = date('j',mktime(0,0,0,date('j'), date('d') + $input,date('Y')));
```

But there are better ways to do this (see other answers).

Comment: Thanks your answer works! However on reflection I agree the other answer is more simply way of going about doing this.